# If a service that I registered with FB/Twitter/G+ is hacked, what mischief can be done with the oauth token?

Tags: oauth, openid

Case in point, TrueCaller. I had logged into TC using a proxy twitter account. I am assuming that as part of the authentication process, an `access_token` must have been saved by TC.

1. If the hackers have this token, what can they be able to do with it?
2. Assuming that the hackers have gotten a hold of my database, what can I as a developer do, to minimise the effect of the leak? What are the good practices for such login?

Thank you.

Comment: Also developers should pay attention to the opposite scenario: Suppose sign in is supported from many accounts (Twitter/Facebook/etc).  Even with double submit cookies, an attacker could still insert a dummy account into what is unused, creating a backdoor.  [Demo @Blackhat here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jauXjSY-9LA)

Answer (score 2):

> 1 . If the hackers have this token, what can they be able to do with it?

That depends on the individual *"social network"*, but such tokens are mostly configured to expire/invalidate after a certain period of time. Also, the networks you mentioned all have multiple security implementations running to limit such attack vectors by — among other things — linking the token to the IP. Ask yourself how *unlikely* it is that an attacker will be able to fetch multiple characteristics simultaneously…  I can't say it'll not happen, as *Murphy's law* would most certainly prove me wrong. ;)

> 2 . Assuming that the hackers have gotten a hold of my database, what can I as a developer do, to minimise the effect of the leak? What are the good practices for such login?

Follow the procedures you would follow in relation to every information security incident — apply the 6 Phases of Incident Management:

1. Preparation
2. Identification
3. Containment
4. Eradication
5. Recovery
6. Training

To dive deeper into *"incident management"*, you might want to start out by checking the following infos:

- [SANS: An Incident Handling Process for Small and Medium
  Businesses](http://www.sans.org/reading_room/whitepapers/incident/incident-handling-process-small-medium-businesses_1791) (PDF)
- [SANS: FORENSICS PLAN GUIDE](http://computer-forensics.sans.org/community/papers/gcfa/forensic-investigation-plan-cookbook_283) (PDF)